# Convert .osm/.pbf to .map for mapsforge

Tags: openstreetmap, java, android, osmosis, mapsforge

I have download latest version (0.46) of osmosis from
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Downloading
and mapsforge-map-writer-0.9.1.jar from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmapsforge-map
and map ("*AM.osm*") from
http://be.gis-lab.info/data/osm_dump/dump/latest/

I'm on Windows-7 64-bit Professional and JDK 1.8u45
I unpacked osmosis to: `c:\Progs\osmosis`
I created a folder called `plugins` in `c:\Progs\osmosis` (>> so: `c:\Progs\osmosis\plugins`)
In the plugins folder I put the file `mapsforge-map-writer-0.9.1.jar`
I put the file `AM.osm.pbf` (and `AM.osm`) into `c:\Progs\osmosis`

I then opened a command-prompt window and executed the following commands:

```
PS C:\Progs\osmosis> osmosis --rb file=AM.osm.pbf --mw file=AM.map

PS C:\Progs\osmosis> osmosis --rx file=AM.osm --mw file=AM.map type=hd
```

I got this error:

```
ьр  23, 2018 9:46:43 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.46
ьр  23, 2018 9:46:43 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
ьр  23, 2018 9:46:43 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/procedure/TShortIntProcedure
        at org.mapsforge.map.writer.model.MapWriterConfiguration.loadTagMappingFile(MapWriterConfiguration.java:351)
        at org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterFactory.createTaskManagerImpl(MapFileWriterFactory.java:58)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactory.createTaskManager(TaskManagerFactory.java:60)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.buildTasks(Pipeline.java:51)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:112)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.procedure.TShortIntProcedure
        at org.java.plugin.standard.StandardPluginClassLoader.loadClass(StandardPluginClassLoader.java:330)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:

there were not enough dependencies, need to download link "[jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/mapsforge/mapsforge-map-writer/0.9.1/mapsforge-map-writer-0.9.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar)"

Error *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError* is solved by parameter "type=hd" (default "type=ram"):

```
C:\Progs\osmosis> osmosis --rb file=local.osm.pbf --mw file=local.osm.map type=hd
```